# Wso2 JAGGERY Publisher

Tags: javascript, wso2, javascript-framework, jaggery-js

I wanted to make a little modification to my publisher info page:

When I go to Browse>API info>Users

I wanted to show the Usage of that api on side, something like

---

**Name  - Date of Subscription - Usage**

### user    - 2012-09-06 10:05:00.085 - 12

What file should I modify to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api-info page template is located at

site/themes/fancy/templates/api/api-info/template.jag [1]

[1] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/apimgt/api-store-web/src/site/themes/fancy/templates/api/api-info/template.jag

Regards,
/Nuwan

Comment: this is on the Store side, I wanted it on the Publisher side, but thank you anyway, I have an idea of where to look now....more or less